# Asp.net - Display word document content stored in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net

We have stored worddocument (office doc/docx files) as varbinary(max) in SQL Server, but when we display its shows data in unformatted way and some encrypted text too...

Document content like:

```
Description about the document :
(a) SQL Server 2016 to be used for all upcoming projects;
(b) SQL Server 2016 Enterprise edition will be used on all servers
(c) Assumptions:
(i) SQL Server will be installed on VM instances

Saved in SQL Server with below code:

create table Documents(id int identity(1,1), document VARBINARY(MAX))
go 

--Insert Word document into database
INSERT INTO Documents(document) 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\found.docx', SINGLE_BLOB) AS doc

select * from documents

        string sConn = @"server=.; database=DocumentManagement; Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConn);
        objConn.Open();
         SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("BLOBViewer", objConn);
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader dr = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Document"]);
        }
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
            Response.End();
```

Comment: Are you sure the dbytes of the document are the only thing being written to the responseo? Do you ened the response afterwards?

Comment: Tried that also... but it didnt work... i have modified code also in question

Comment: I think you also have to modify the Response.Headers to identify to the user's browser that the file you are sending is a Word doc, otherwise it will be treated as an HTML file.

Answer (score 3):

Native .NET does not support reading word documents.
You'll have to use some third party tools to achieve this.
We mostly use [Aspose.Word](https://products.aspose.com/words/net) It allows you to even do more than just reading its content; you can manipulate it too. But there is a price to it.

If you are looking for something free then I'd suggest you to convert your word documents into PDF and then store them in DB. There are tons of free libraries you can use to read a PDF file's content. [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) and [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) are just two examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can neatly download a file. This is assuming it is stored correctly in SQL.

However this only works for 1 file at a time. You cannot select all files with `select * from documents` and expect them to be downloaded as individual files, it does not work like that. So you have to create a Stored Procedure that selects one file at a time: `select * from documents WHERE (Name = 'FileName')` or something similar.

```
//declare an empty byte array and filename
byte[] bin = new byte[0];
string fileName = "";

//use 'using' to properly close and dispose connections and objects
using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConn))
using (SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("BLOBViewer", objConn))
{
    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objConn.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader dr = objCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            bin = (byte[])dr["Document"];
            fileName = dr["Name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}

//check if there is a file
if (bin.Length == 0)
{
    Label1.Text = "No file found";
    return;
}

//send the file to the browser
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);
Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: I don't want to download I have to display content in grid pls

Comment: Huh? Then why the `BinaryWrite`, `Flush` & `End`? But you want to display multiple Word documents in a GridView???

Comment: That's the requirement I have from end user to display them

Comment: Better have a chat with the end user that this makes no sense. If you want to display data why store a word document as a blob in an sql server?

Comment: Word document is of 320 page. We extracted portion of word document (e.g. few paras from whole document which client ways), save them in separate file and then display them in grid or any other way on asp page under some grouping

Comment: Why not to store `few paras` directly in a sql column and just read it directly?